# a random port is chosen while initing socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, port

```
int create_socket(struct in_addr *ip, unsigned int port) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = (port); 
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
    connect(s, &sin, sizeof(sin));
    return s;
}
```

I try to create socket to connect to of my server, and whenever I run this code the process tries to connect to a random socket.
the function is called with the following parameters:

```
inet_aton(argv[1], &ip); //argv[1]=='127.0.0.1'
unsigned int port = htons(atoi(argv[2])); //argv[2]=='8080'
```

Anyone detects the mistake?

Comment: What is the *exact* actual problem? The client side will use a random port above the floor threshold of well-knowns. The *server* should still be using the specified listen port. If you're expecting the client to connect to the server using the same port client-side as specified for the server-side, that's not how `connect` works.

Comment: @WhozCraig I believe he wants to connect to the designated port which is 8080 and not  a random one.

Comment: @thecorrectanswer doesn't change what I said, nor what I asked, in the slightest.

Comment: How are you telling what port it's trying to connect to?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer Then he'd do best by actually checking the return value from `connect()`....

Comment: @WhozCraig The question says "the process tries to connect to a random socket". What else are you asking?

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I know. that's a neat trick all its own (the "random socket" part). This is begging for clarification from the OP, which is what I (thought) I asked for.

Comment: @WhozCraig I believe that the server listens in the right port 8080, and he wants that the client will also be connected to this port. but instead it tries to connect to a random one.

Comment: The code you posted should connect to whatever is in the `port` variable. Use a debugger and make sure it has the value you expect.

Comment: Maybe you have undefined behavior elsewhere in the code, so the variable is being overwritten. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Use a debugger, not `printf()` statements. Adding new code can change the memory layout, so the effect of the UB could change (this is where heisenbugs come from).

Comment: You can do a [debug] `printf` on `port` in both server and client. The client will probably print something you're not expecting. So, we'd need to see the client code that sets that value [and the "chain of custody" for it].

Comment: port is 36895 which should be htons(8080) no?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer I've no doubt the server is (probably) listening on the correct port. I've not-as-solid-no-doubt the client is possibly even connecting. I have a *substantial* doubt the OP understands what I described in my first comment as the way `connect` works, which is both why I wrote it, and why I asked for the specific nature of the actual  problem. I suggest the OP is not understanding that just because the server socket is listening on port 8080, that doesn't mean the client socket will use that same port client-side when connecting, and in fact, it's highly unlikely.

Comment: @MrP Checking the success/failure of `connect` notwithstanding (you really should) do you understand pretty-much my entire first comment (and the one above, for that matter) ?

Comment: what I try, is to connect the server which listens for port 8080 to the client which try to connect in port 8080. why it fails?

Comment: How do you know it fails ? you never checked the result of `connect`. And if it does return -1 then `errno` should be set to the actual error, which you can further use to drill into the real problem.

Comment: Well, if the printed value of `port` is 36895, that's [obviously] wrong [since you want 8080]. So, what is the code that _sets_ it? Also, remember that you're [probably] on a little-endian machine. So, print the port value _before_ you use `htons` on it.

Comment: @CraigEstey `8080` in hex is `0x1F90`, so doing an endian swap means it should be `0x901F`, which is `36895`, assuming it's carried through as unsigned the entire way - but the use of an `unsigned int` instead of the proper `unsigned short` does have a nasty code smell, so I'm wondering what's been left out.  But making sure the value is correct from the beginning is certainly a good idea, as the use of `atoi()` only adds to the smell.

Comment: @AndrewHenle how would you change it?

Comment: @WhozCraig connect never returns. it just stuck waiting for a response that never comes.

Comment: @MrP You're finding out exactly why cramming operation after operation into one line like `unsigned int port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));` is ***BAD CODE***.  You can't debug it - you have no idea what any of the intermediate values are.  Nevermind the fact `atoi()` has absolutely no way to indicate an error condition.  Separate the code into separate lines using a *robust* function like `strtol()` to convert the string to a `long` while checking for errors.  If the value is proper, then convert it to an `unsigned short` using `htons()`.  You can actually debug that code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good catch. I put the values into `kcalc` to check that but didn't see it [I'm way behind on coffee here :-)]

Comment: I typed :
    int hostshort = atoi(argv[2]);
which is 8080
@AndrewHenle

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the client code that _sets_ `port` (vs. giving us small fragments piecemeal in comments). As Andrew said, use `unsigned short port`. And, use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. But, after the `atoi/strtol` line, you need: `port = htons(port);`

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```cpp
int create_socket(struct in_addr *ip, unsigned short port) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) return -1;

    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(port);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = ip->s_addr;

    if (connect(s, &sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        close(s);
        s = -1;
    }

    return s;
}
```

```cpp
struct in_addr ip;
inet_aton(argv[1], &ip); //argv[1]=="127.0.0.1"
unsigned short port = atoi(argv[2]); //argv[2]=="8080"
int sckt = create_socket(&ip, port);
if (sckt < 0) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
    close(sckt);
}
```

A better option is to use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) instead, let it do all the parsing and setup of the `sockaddr_in` for you:

```cpp
int create_socket(const char *ip, const char *port) {
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs, *addr;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    int res = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, &addrs);
    if (res < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for(addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next) {
        int s = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (s < 0) continue;

        if (connect(s, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
            freeaddrinfo(addrs);
            return s;
        }

        close(s);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    return -1;
}
```

```cpp
int sckt = create_socket(argv[1], argv[2]);
if (sckt < 0) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
    close(sckt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this:

```
int create_socket(struct in_addr *ip, unsigned int port) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = (port); 
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr =ip->s_addr; // this is where the problem was
    err_handler(connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)));
    return s;
}
```